# Copy activity giving error when I change to actual sql datatype in Source dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a simple copy activity, copying from blob csv to Az SQL.

As I import schema on mapping tab, as usual at source I get all strings. So I need to change to respective date, double, int datatypes for my csv to map them with my SQL. I changed them through json code referring to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB446EB_-aU

But I get this error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that ADF cannot convert the string value from CSV to date value in SQL. These may be due to different date formats.

Try to use the Type conversion settings at the top of the mapping tab to set the correct date format, based on what you see in your CSV.
[image: type convertion settings]

Comment: Actually i have seen the file ,the col contains Nulls , so now how to handle this .Even thought i tried to give yyyy-MM-dd. It doenot worked because the col contains nulls. Can we handle this ?

Comment: @AzSuryaTeja, If you need to handle null values, you may have to use data flows instead of the copy activity. Another option is to write to a staging table in SQL where all columns are strings, and then run SQL code to load into your actual destination table with correct data types.